# Deleted GAE OAuth2 ClientID, cannot recreate

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth

I had originally created the project under my personal account. Decided to move it to my Business Google Apps account.

1. From my personal account, I deleted the OAuth keys in my old project
   and then deleted the project.
2. Switched to my business account and selected the project.
3. From the credentials screen, I attempted to create an OAuth key for my Android project. I received the error that the fingerprint was globally unique and already in use.
4. Switched back to my personal account, undeleted the project and verified that the keys were indeed deleted. There are no keys listed on the credentials screen. To add insult, attempting to create the keys there also results in the same error as I was experiencing in my business account copy of the project.

A possible confounding error may have been that I did delete the project under my personal account without deleting the OAuth keys and then restored the project.

I have searched multiple threads and have not seen any solution that wasn't a Google engineer fixing the error or to change your Android app name (really rather not take that path, app is already published to a pool of testers).

*Edit*
The original project is still pending deletion. After a week the message has changed to a server error. It has an undefined tracking number. I'm hoping this is some sort of progress and that things will work after the original project is actually deleted. Will post an update once that happens.